# Where can I find historical taxation/revenue datasets for imperial countries in the early 20th century?

Tags: 20th-century, colonization, historical-research, resource, public-finance

I'm a grad student trying to conduct research, and my project depends on finding a dataset which enumerates taxation and revenue by colonial-era and post-colonial governments within the early 20th century. The British colonial blue books offer a lot of good primary source data for Africa specifically, but this is somewhat lacking on its own. Given how distinct colonialism in Africa was from colonialism elsewhere (with African colonialism focusing more on extraction than settlement), failing to address cases outside of Africa would be pretty flawed. I also can't limit myself exclusively to British colonies, since there's a wealth of literature claiming that the colonial strategies employed by the British fostered distinct institutions from the colonialism of other metropolitan nations.

In short, I need a large dataset of state revenue expenditures, the composition of those expenditures (e.g. how much was spent on military, how much on healthcare, how much on education, etc.), and taxation within the early 20th century. This should preferably cover both colonial and non-colonial governments during that time period.

I'm more than willing to accept a dataset which covers only part of these specifications. I'd be very grateful for any help. Thanks.

EDIT: I assumed this was obvious, but "colonial govts" here refers to the govts of colonial dependencies that remained under European control at the start of the 20th century (e.g. French West Africa, Indochine, British African colonies, etc.).

Comment: [Our world in data](https://ourworldindata.org/taxation)??   I might also point out that "colonialism" in the early 20th century is quite distinct from colonialism in prior centuries.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the historical taxation data covers only a handful of european nations. I need data for colonial governments.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "*colonial governments*" and "*early 20th century*"?. The various [Dominions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion#Dominions) became such as: Canada 1867, Australia 1901, New Zealand and Newfoundland in 1907, and Union of South Africa in 1910. With such status they became financially independent of the United kingdom, fully managing their own revenues expenses, currency and finances.

Comment: I'm referring to the colonies that were still held at that point: French West Africa, Indochina, British holdings in Africa, etc.

Comment: @LysanderCox: Please edit all clarifications into the question itself. Comments are ephemeral, and subject to deletion or chat-migration at any time, and without warning. Questions must stand independent of them.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Newfoundland after it became a dominion is quite relevant, since financial failure caused it to revert to being a colony in 1933.

Comment: @CMonsour: 1933 is an interesting, to say the least, delineation for "*early part of the 20th century*". I would regard everything from January, 1933, - and perhaps even November i932 - as clearly mid-20th century.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The roots of its financial failure obviously extend back many years prior to 1933.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens And the first third of the 20th century ended roughly April 30, 1934.  (There was no year 0, so the first century was 1-100, and so on.)

Answer (score 1):

[International Historical Statistics](https://link.springer.com/referencework/10.1057%2F978-1-137-30568-8) from Palgrave Macmillan might be worth a look. But overall I suspect it's unlikely that you'll find a pre-existing dataset that covers your needs. [Ewout Frankema](https://www.ewoutfrankema.com/) has published a few relevant studies like [this](https://www.ewoutfrankema.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Raising_Revenue.JGH_.2010.pdf) and [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227416793_Colonial_taxation_and_government_spending_in_British_Africa_1880-1940_Maximizing_revenue_or_minimizing_effort) and he is pulling his data directly from the Blue Books.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer. it suggests a possible location of an answer, but is not an answer because (1) author has not verified the usefulness of said resource; and (2) it's a link-only answer, and thus defined by site TOS as not being an answer.

Comment: Funny you mention Frankema. He was actually what motivated me to seek this data.

Comment: Do you know of anything similar to blue books for french colonies in the same period?

Comment: On French colonies Frankema has co-authored with van Waijenburg and they list the equivalent sources: https://www.ewoutfrankema.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/MetropolitanBlueprintsColonialTaxation.JAH_.2014.pdf